# How to hide weblogic password in jenkins console

Tags: java, jenkins

We are using Weblogic Deployer Plugin for Jenkins 1.5 to deploy wars via Jenkins in Weblogic servers. The source, target & credentials are managed through default.xml file.

```
<weblogic-target>
        <name>WeblogicServer</name>
        <host>localhost</host>
        <port>9001</port>
        <login>JenkinsUser</login>
        <password>deploy</password>
        <authMode>BY_LOGIN</authMode>
    </weblogic-target>
```

But in the console output of Jenkins, the password is being shown as plaintext. We have installed Mask Password plugin & configured it, but this is of no help.

Can someone put forward any idea about hiding this password from appearing in the Jenkins console output?

Comment: I think that Mask Password is the right way to go, but are you sure you have configured it properly?

Comment: Yes, I've configured Mask Password as per the instructions provided in the setup page of Jenkins. But Mask Password only seems to hide any password used as parameters in Jenkins main settings page or if I use any Global User ID - Password combo. This is not hiding the password used in weblogic deployer plugin's setup file default.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it! Weblogic Deployer Plugin version 2.3 onwards has built in capability of hiding password. It uses Weblogic's password encryption functionality. I had to just modify the default.xml like this:

```
<weblogic-target>
            <name>WeblogicServer</name>
            <host>localhost</host>
            <port>9001</port>
            <login>JenkinsUser</login>
            <password>deploy</password>
            <authMode>BY_KEY</authMode>
            <userconfigfile>C:\users\MyUser\Desktop\userconfig</userconfigfile>
            <userkeyfile>C:\users\MyUser\Desktop\userkey</userkeyfile>
 </weblogic-target>
```

The userconfigfile & userkeyfile are a properties-key file pair which can be generated from either WLST script or cmd. For everyone's convenience am providing the commands below:

Go to your weblogic server installation folder --> bin, open cmd inside that folder & type setWLSEnv + enter.

java weblogic.Admin -adminurl t3://localhost:9001 -userid **userid** -password **password** -userconfigfile "Your designated path to store the file" -userkeyfile "Your designated path to store the file" -STOREUSERCONFIG

It will ask for confirmation, press Y & enter, the pair of files will be created. you can validate if this pair works by the following command:

java weblogic.Admin -adminurl t3://localhost:9001 -userconfigfile "Local path where you stored the confing file in previous step" -userkeyfile "Local path where you stored the key file in previous step" -GETSTATE

If it shows RUNNING then the file is working fine!

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use [Mask Password Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Mask+Passwords+Plugin) you can use the regex: `-password\s.*` in your job configuration.

[image: MaskPasswordRegEx]