# Weblogic 11g: How to encrypt "-Dweblogic.management.password"?

Tags: oracle, encryption, oracle11g, weblogic, weblogic12c

I am working on Weblogic 11g that installed on Linux system.
When i am running the following command:

```
ps -ef | grep weblogic | grep Admin
```

then in output i can see the User-name and the Password for loging into Admin console as a Plain-text:

```
 -Dweblogic.management.username
 -Dweblogic.management.password
```

How can i encrypted it so it would not be so obvious.

Comment: [Use a `boot.properties` file instead.](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/fmw/wls/12c/15-BootProp--4471/bootproperties.htm)

Comment: perhaps, the approved answer here may help yours : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34356994/how-to-hide-weblogic-password-in-jenkins-console

Comment: Use a password verifier. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt`, `passlib.hash` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.